# Is axis_camera working in groovy?

Tags: ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is axis_camera working in groovy?

I did

```
git clone https://github.com/clearpathrobotics/axis_camera.git
```

but when running I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/tompe/ros_groovy_git/axis_camera/nodes/axis.py", line 13, in <module>
    import camera_info_manager
ImportError: No module named camera_info_manager
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/67113/is-axis_camera-working-in-groovy?/) by [TommyP](https://answers.ros.org/users/1110/tommyp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1339 on 2013-07-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you installed camera_info_manager_py? For instance, by doing sudo apt-get install ros-groovy-camera-info-manager-py?

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2013-07-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TommyP](https://answers.ros.org/users/1110/tommyp/) on 2013-07-11**:
No, I had not done that since "apt-file search camera_info_manager_py" only returned fuerte packages. This is annoying since I trust apt-file. I thought that the apt-file indexing was fixed...

**Comment by [TommyP](https://answers.ros.org/users/1110/tommyp/) on 2013-07-11**:
After installing ros-groovy-camera-info-manager-py the server starts at least.

**Comment by [TommyP](https://answers.ros.org/users/1110/tommyp/) on 2013-07-11**:
And the display of the image worked also. I am using an Axis P7214 Video Encoder.